# JSdoc: Dynamic key name of return object

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdoc

```js
/**
 * 
 * @param {string} key 
 * @param {any} value
 * @returns {{[key]: typeof value}} 
 */
const set = (key, value) => {
    return {[key]: value}
}

const myObj = set("country", "USA")

myObj. // should suggest .country key
```

I can not understand how correct define key name of return object

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following would do the trick. Just use [`@template`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#template) to type it as a generic function.

```js
/**
 * @template {string} K
 * @template T
 * @param {K} key
 * @param {T} value
 * @returns {Record<K, T>}
 */
const set = (key, value) => {
  return {[key]: value}
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It okay to get type of value and inherit it, but I need dynamic name of object property.

Comment: Like I call `const myObj = set("mySuperPropery", "myValue")`.
and when I type `myObj.` IDE should suggest the key `mySuperPropery`

Comment: Oh, I see now. I've updated the answer to make it work with auto-complete suggestions.